# Printing a CSV table on a webpage using flask

Tags: python, html, csv, pandas, flask

So I tried using pandas to create the dataframe and finally convert it to an html file and put the data in dataset.html. So I left the dataset.html file empty. But when I run this, the '/dataset' page is empty. How do I fix this?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')    
def home_page():    
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/dataset')    
def another_page():    
    table = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("Soccer.csv")
    return render_template("dataset.html", data=table.to_html)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: What's the content of your dataset.html template file?

Comment: Its empty. What should I put in there? I thought the data=table.to_html would add the html code of the table in there.

Comment: Read the flask docs. This is explained very clearly. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: You need to put something like this `{{ data | safe }}` into the template file.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `data=table.to_html()` `to_html()` is a function